# SpriteKitのノードをボタンにしてカメラを使いたい

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone, spritekit

初めまして。プログラミング初心者です。

SpriteKitで"cbutton"と名付けたノードをタップするとカメラが起動して写真を撮影し、撮影した写真をカメラロールに保存して元の画面(GameScene)に戻る、という処理をしたいのですがうまくいきません。

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    //背景画像、ボタンのスプライトを配置
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "haikei")
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5,y: self.size.height * 0.5)
    addChild(background)

    let cbutton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cbutton")
    cbutton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.25, y: 100)
    cbutton.name = "cbutton"
    addChild(cbutton)

    }

// cbuttonのタッチイベント作成
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if self.nodeAtPoint(location).name == "cbutton" {

            // カメラ起動
            let camera = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(camera){
                let picker = UIImagePickerController()
                picker.sourceType = camera
                picker.delegate = self
                self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){

                let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
                let gameScene = GameScene(size: size)
                let skView = view as SKView!
                gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFit
                skView.presentScene(gameScene)       
            }                
        }        
    }
}
```

下から14行目の
self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
で、"Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'presentViewController'"とエラーが起こってしまいます。

ViewControllerは以下のようになっています。

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = self.view as! SKView

    // SKGameSceneを生成
    let scene =  GameScene(size:CGSize(width: 375, height: 667))
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFit

    // SKView に SKScene を設定して表示させる
    skView.presentScene(scene)    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

*バージョンはXcode7.2, Swift2.1です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'presentViewController'

このエラーメッセーの意味を理解することから始めましょう。
クラス`GameScene`は、`SKScene`を継承し、`UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`プロトコルを採用しています。そして、`SKScene`は、`SKEffectNode`のサブクラスであり、`SKEffectNode`は、`SKNode`のサブクラスであり、`SKNode`は、`UIResponder`のサブクラスであり、`UIResponder`は、`NSObject`のサブクラスです。これらのクラスおよびプロトコルの中のどれかが、`presentViewController`というメンバー（メソッドあるいはプロパティ）を持っていれば、このエラーは起きません。どれも持っていないので、エラーとなります。
`presentViewController`は、クラス`UIViewController`のメソッド

```
func presentViewController(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,
                  animated flag: Bool,
                completion completion: (() -> Void)?)
```

のことです。

```
self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

この`self`は、クラス`GameScene`の実装内で使われているので、`GameScene`のインスタンスを指します。`UIViewController`（のサブクラス）のインスタンスを指していません。なので、`self`を（`UIViewController`のサブクラスである）`ViewController`のインスタンスと置き換えなければいけません。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。

なるほど、presentViewControllerのメソッドを親クラスが持っていなかったのが悪かったのですね。
では、GameSceneに、同時にUIViewControllerも継承させるか、presentViewControllerのメソッドをクラス内に記述するかをすればいいのでしょうか。

selfを置き換える部分を、自分なりに書き換えてみました。

'                 let viewcontroller = ViewController()
                 picker.delegate = self
                 viewcontroller.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
'
これでエラーは出ませんでしたが、実機でビルドしてボタンをタップしたら落ちてしまいました。
そのとき、ViewController.swiftの

' let skView = self.view as! SKView'

の行に"Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"
とエラーが出ていました。

やはり置き換えるインスタンスがおかしいのでしょうか。

Comment: はい、おかしいですね。SpriteKit以前に、SwiftとCocoa touch（iOSのフレームワークのこと）の基礎を勉強しなおされることを、強く、強くお勧めします。